# C# Xml Parse SelectNodes

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, foreach, selectnodes

I have the next xml code:

```
<Start>
       <MetricValue>
                    <Name>Name1</Name>
                    <Value>1</Value>
       </MetricValue>
       <MetricValue>
                    <Name>Name1</Name>
                    <Value>1</Value>
       </MetricValue>
       <Test>
             <MetricValue>
                          <Name>Name1</Name>
                          <Value>1</Value>
             </MetricValue>
             <MetricValue>
                          <Name>Name1</Name>
                          <Value>1</Value>
             </MetricValue>
       </Test>
</Start>
```

I am trying to parse only the first 2 metric values and not that from between 'Test' tags.

```
XmlNodeList nlMetricValues = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Start//MetricValue");
foreach (XmlNode nMetricValue in nlMetricValues)
{
        Console.WriteLine("\Name: " + nMetricValue.SelectSingleNode(".//Name").InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine("\tValue: " + nMetricValue.SelectSingleNode(".//Value")).InnerText);
}
```

But this foreach is parsing all metric values. What should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the XPath used to select the MetricValue nodes as that is where the problem likely is.

Comment: Done. I've added the xmlnode too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `XPath` should be `"./Start/MetricValue"` as `"//"` means it will search the node tree for any match below the previous node.

Link to syntax cheatsheet: [W3Schools - XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements(v=vs.110).aspx) of `XElement` class. It will load only the `MetricValue` elements that are the children of `Start` element:

```
var xml = @"
<Start>
    <MetricValue>
        <Name>Name1</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </MetricValue>
    <MetricValue>
        <Name>Name1</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </MetricValue>
    <Test>
        <MetricValue>
            <Name>Name1</Name>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </MetricValue>
        <MetricValue>
            <Name>Name1</Name>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </MetricValue>
    </Test>
</Start>";

var metricValues = XElement.Parse(xml).Elements("MetricValue");
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `XElement.Parse(xml).Element("Start").Elements("MetricValue");` ?

Comment: @toadflakz, nope, not really. The root element here is `Start` so you don't need another call to `Element()` method.

Comment: Right you are - I've typically always used `XDocument.Parse()` and would need the extra `Element()` call which is why I queried it - obviously `XElement.Parse()` returns `XElement`, not `XDocument`! Oops!